# Where do I find Archive versions of Mule Studio?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I was looking for archived releases of mule studio, mainly 3.4.0 because there only seems to be the latest and greatest on the Mulesoft site. I managed to find this site that has all of their archives from 3.4.0.

http://mule-studio-releases.s3.amazonaws.com/

The site will pop up an XML. There is an element called "Key" which is the actual URI of the download. If you append the key to the url above, your download will commence. I hope this helps anyone else looking for older versions of mule studio.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want that? You can use 3.4.0 runtime in the latest version by installing that runtime from the update site: http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes/. Which by the way is already registered in Studio.

[image]